# Find the start index (in string) of capture [JS/RegExp]

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there anyway I can find the index (in string) of my RegExp capture? eg ...

```
var str = "hello world";
var regex = /lo (wo)/;
var match = regex.exec(str);
// what I want is something like 
var index = match[1].index; // where index = 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOf()` should give you what you want:

```
var index = str.indexOf(match[1]);
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/HgFWF)

If you want to loop through each match, you need to add a `g` modifier to your regex, loop through it and call `indexOf()` each time. In your loop you pass a second argument to `indexOf()` to tell it where to start looking.

```
var str = "hello world hello world";
var regex = /lo (wo)/g;
var match;
var prevIndex, currIndex;
var indexes = [];

while (match = regex.exec(str)) {
    currIndex = str.indexOf(match[1], prevIndex);
    indexes.push(currIndex);
    prevIndex = regex.lastIndex;
}
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/5gPh6)

Comment: This will fail if there are multiple matches, and I am looping through all of them. eg. `"Hello World Hello World"`. You know, when I am processing the 2nd match, the capture is the same, so I think this method is not reliable

Comment: @jiewmeng: It is reliable, if you do it right. You need to iterate over all matches, increasing the start index by the last index every time a match is found. You'll get exact results.

Comment: @jiewmeng: See my updated answer for how to loop through the matches.

Comment: This doesn't work with subcaptures, consider the following example: "00-11-00" and /((\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}))/. The first capture would be "00-11-00" and will advance prevIndex pass the full values leaving out captures "00", "11" and "00" unable to identified.

Comment: @alex: You're right. I'll see if I can find a fix for that, but I wasn't considering subcaptures when I first wrote this answer. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @BoltClock: I'm currently struggling with this problem as well :(

Comment: Unbelievable that JS doesn't indicate the index of the capture! This solution won't work if you have a specific regex. For instance, `abc abc` and the regex `^abc (.+)$`. If I try to find the index of the capture at index 1, i will be told it is at index 0 in the string, when in reality it was found at index 4.

Comment: this is a massive hack that will happen to work much of the time, then become a debugging nightmare when it suddenly doesn't.  please don't put landmines like this in your code, especially ones that look innocuous.

Comment: @Eevee: I see what you mean. I wonder if anything's been added to solve this problem natively; otherwise, a more robust solution would (still) be out of my league.